# How to fix Webscraping IndexError

Tags: python

I am trying to get data for IFPI 2014 data into an csv file. However I keep getting this index error.

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Brian\eclipse-workspace\FTS\src\FirstModule.py", line 15, in 
    tbody = soup('table', {"class":"wikitable plainrowheaders sortable jquery-tablesorter"})[0].find_all('tr')
IndexError: list index out of range

---

I have noticed that the csv file was created but no data was inside the csv file. I don't understand as to why its giving me this error message because as I understand it the indexing is correct.

```
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('dataoutput.csv', 'w', newline = '')
writer = csv.writer(f)
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_music_industry_market_share_data").read(), 'lxml')

tbody = soup('table', {"class":"wikitable plainrowheaders sortable 
jquery-tablesorter"})[0].find_all('tr')
for row in tbody:
    cols = row.findChildren(recursive=False)
    cols = [ele.text.script() for ele in cols]
    writer.writerow(cols)
    print(cols)
```

Can someone please point out to me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the page via a REST request no css or js attributes have been added. 
The following code snippet was returning data for me:

```
tbody = soup('table', {"class":"wikitable plainrowheaders sortable"})[0].find_all('tr')
```